# Marcadores duplicados no Google Maps, mesmo com cache desativado!

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Olá, estou trabalhando com o google maps, estava indo tudo ok, mas quando comecei a usar os marcadores, os mesmos 
estão ficando duplicados em alguns locais, isso acontece quando estou andando e fico parado em algum local, 
quando me movo novamente e o GPS atualiza minha posição, no local onde fiquei parado fica um marcado, como se fosse um cache,
mas do modo que estou manuseando os marcadores não era para isso acontecer, já desativei o cache da pagina e nada,
se já aconteceu com alguém ou se alguém tiver alguma dica ficarei muito grato, obrigado pela atenção,
estarei colocando  o código que usei para desativar o cache no navegador e como estou atualizando os marcadores no mapa.

Meta tags para desativar o cache

Remove todos os marcadores para atualiza-los,
fiz isso para ver se parava de duplicar

```
$.each(markers, function(index, marker) {
    marker.setMap(null);
});
```

======================================================================

Essa variável é criada no inicio do script

var markers = [];

aqui é o conteúdo de uma função que fica dando get com as informações dos dispositivos (devices)

```
if (markers[device.id] == undefined) {
    markers[device.id] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: { lat: device.lat, lng: device.lng },
        map: map,
        title: device.name
    });
} else {
    markers[device.id].setPosition( { lat: device.lat, lng: device.lng } );
}
```

Comment: tenho um script parecido. A diferença está no if, estou usando 'if (markers.hasOwnProperty(device.id)) {' . Você verificou se está caindo no else corretamente?

Comment: Sim amigo, os marcadores estão sendo atualizados perfeitamente, o que me parece é ser algo relacionado a cache, mas já desativei o cache com meta tags e desativei o cache de views do frame work que estou utilizando,  Laravel 5.2, e isso só acontece quando o GPS fica parado (algumas vezes), quando ele atualiza a posição fica um marcador onde ele estava, como se fosse de algum cache!